# Append additional conditions to a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequel

I have a query where I need to add several conditions as an `OR` clause, because I want to use `LIKE`, so I can not use `IN` instead.

So how can I add multiple `OR` from an array?

The SQL should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where a like '%a%' OR a LIKE '%b%' OR a LIKE '%c%' ...
```

where 'a', 'b', 'c' is from an array.

```
dataset
   .where(column:, Sequel.like(:column, '%#{myarray.first}%'))

myarray.drop(1).each do |v|
    dataset.or(Sequel.like(:column, '%#{v}%'))
end

dataset.limit(100)
```

Comment: Where is `SQL.like` coming from and how is it implemented? That is not a standard Rails method.

Comment: I updated the question. It was ' Sequel' not 'SQL'. Copy&Paste error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Rails API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or), the `.or` conditional query should be chained *after* a `.where` method.

```rb
dataset.where(column:, Sequel.like(:column, '%#{myarray.first}%'))
       .or(dataset.where(column:, Sequel.like(:column, '%#{myarray.second}%'))
       .or(dataset.where(column:, Sequel.like(:column, '%#{myarray.third}%'))
```

The full answer:

```rb
dataset = dataset.where(column:, Sequel.like(:column, '%#{myarray.first}%'))

myarray.drop(1).each do |v|
    dataset = dataset.or(dataset.where(column:, Sequel.like(:column, '%#{v}%'))
end

dataset.limit(100)
```

The same can be achieved without a gem (assuming `Sequel.like` is coming from this [gem](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel)) in "vanilla" Rails.

```rb
dataset = dataset.where("column LIKE ?", '%#{myarray.first}%'))

myarray.drop(1).each do |v|
    dataset = dataset.or(dataset.where("column LIKE ?", '%#{v}%'))
end

dataset.limit(100)
```